# Are there django flatblocks with support for translations

Tags: django, internationalization

I really like [django-flatblocks](https://github.com/zerok/django-flatblocks) app but the one thing missing is internationalization support (i.e. defining content of a block in different languages). Are there any similar apps that offer this feature?

Comment: Nice plugin, never heard of it before. +1